# Best data structure in C for these two situations?

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, hashtable, hashmap

I kinda need to decide on this to see if I can achieve it in a couple of hours before the deadline for my school project is due but I don't understand much about data structures and I need suggestions...

There's 2 things I need to do, they will probably use different data structures.

1. I need a data structure to hold profile records. The profiles must be search able by name and social security number. The SSN is unique, so I probably can use that for my advantage? I suppose hash maps is the best bet here? But how do I use the SSN in an hash map to use that as an advantage in looking for a specific profile? A basic and easy to understand explanation would be much appreciated.
2. I need a data structure to hold records about cities. **I need to know which are cities with most visitors, cities less visited and the clients** (the profile is pulled from the data structure in #1 for data about the clients) **that visit a specific city**.

This is the third data structure I need for my project and it's the data structure that I have no idea where to begin. Suggestions as for which type of data structure to use are appreciated, if possible, with examples on how to old the data above in bold.

**As a note:**
The first data structure is already done (I talked about it in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670301/how-to-search-a-specific-node-in-a-graph-structure-in-c)). The second one is posted here on #1 and although the other group members are taking care of that I just need to know if what we are trying to do is the "best" approach. The third one is #2, the one I need most help.

Comment: Be careful about assumptions like "SSN is unique". It is *supposed* to be unique, but there are no guarantees. Think "identity theft": what happens when both the victim and thief need records in your system...

Comment: This is the problem with homework questions.  In real life, you'd use a database.  You should ask questions how to pick the indexes right to optimize the queries.

Comment: Right, but this is just a school project, there's no need to think about "identity theft" or something like that. This is just to evaluate our knowledge, it's not a real application.

Answer (score 3):

The *right* answer lies anywhere between a balanced search tree and an array.

The situation you have mentioned here and else-thread misses out on a *very* important point: The size of the data you are handling. You choose your data structure and algorithm(s) depending on the amount of data you have to handle. It is important that you are able to justify your choice(s). Using a less efficient general algorithm is not always *bad*. Being able to back up your choices (e.g: choosing bubble-sort since data size < 10 always) shows a) greater command of the field and b) pragmatism -- both of which are in short supply.

Comment: He has to be able to search a single data set on multiple keys.That complicates the problem if his data set is big enough for linear time to be a problem. Which does nothing to detract for your point about the size of the data set being an important consideration.

Comment: @dmckee: I could figure that much out. And I left my answer vague intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

For searchability across multiple keys, store the data in any convenient form, and provides fast lookup indexes on the key(s).

This could be as simple as keeping the data in an array (or linked list, or ...) in the order of creation, and keeping a bunch of {hashtables|sorted arrays|btrees} of maps `(key, data*)` for all the interesting keys (SSN, name, ...).

If you had more time, you could even work out how to *not* have a different `struct` for each different map...

I think this solution probably applies to both your problems.

Good luck.

---

For clarity:

First we have a simple array of student records

```
typedef
struct student_s {
   char ssn[10]; // nul terminated so we can use str* functions 
   char name[100];
   float GPA;
   ...
} student;
student slist[MAX_STUDENTS];
```

which is filled in as you go. It has no order, so search on *any* key is a linear time operation. Not a problem for 1,000 entries, but maybe a problem for 10,000, and certainly a problem for 1 million. See [dirkgently's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670536/best-data-structure-in-c-for-these-two-situations/670559#670559).

If we want to be able to search fast we need another layer of structure. I build a map between a key and the main data structure like this:

```
typedef
struct str_map {
   char* key;
   student *data;
} smap;
smap skey[MAX_STUDENTS]
```

and maintain skey *sorted* on the key, so that I can do fast lookups. (Only an array is a hassle to *keep* sorted, so we probably prefer a tree, or a hashmap.)

This complexity isn't needed (and should certainly be avoided) if you will only want fast searches on a single field.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of a homework question, you'd use a relational database for
this. But that probably doesn't help you…

The first thing you need to figure out, as others have already pointed
out, is how much data you're handling. An O(*n*) brute-force search is
plenty fast as long a *n* is small. Since a trivial amount of data would
make this a trivial problem (put it in an array, and just brute-force
search it), I'm going to assume the amount of data is large.

### Storing Cities

First, your search requirements appear to require the data sorted in
multiple ways:

1. Some city unique identifier (name?)
2. Number of visitors

This actually isn't too hard to satisfy. (1) is easiest. Store the
cities in some array. The array index becomes the unique identifier
(assumption: we aren't deleting cities, or if we do delete cities we can
just leave that array spot unused, wasting some memory. Adding is OK).

Now, we also need to be able to find most & fewest visits. Assuming
modifications may happen (e.g., adding cities, changing number of
visitors, etc.) and borrowing from relational databases, I'd suggest
creating an index using some form of balanced tree. Databases would
commonly use a B-Tree, but different ones may work for you: check [Wikipedia's
article on trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_data_structure). In each tree node, I'd just keep a pointer (or
array index) of the city data. No reason to make another copy!

I recommend a tree over a hash for one simple reason: you can very
easily do a preorder or reverse order traversal to find the top or
bottom N items. A hash can't do that.

Of course, if modifications may not happen, just use another array (of
pointers to the items, once again, don't duplicate them).

### Linking Cities to Profiles

How to do this depends on how you have to query the data, and what form
it can take. The most general is that each profile can be associated
with multiple cities and each city can be associated with multiple
profiles. Further, we want to be able to efficiently query from either
direction — ask both "who visits Phoenix?" and "which cities does Bob
visit?".

Shamelessly lifting from databases again, I'd create another data
structure, a fairly simple one along the lines of:

```
struct profile_city {
    /* btree pointers here */
    size_t profile_idx; /* or use a pointer */
    size_t city_idx;    /* for both indices */
};
```

So, to say Bob (profile 4) has visited Phoenix (city 2) you'd have
`profile_idx = 4` and `city_idx = 2`. To say Bob has visited Vegas (city
1) as well, you'd add another one, so you'd have two of them for Bob.

Now, you have a choice: you can store these either in a tree or a
hash. Personally, I'd go with the tree, since that code is already
written. But a hash would be O(*n*) instead of O(log*n*) for lookups.

Also, just like we did for the city visit count, create an index for
`city_idx` so the lookup can be done from that side too.

### Conclusion

You now have a way to look up the 5 most-visited cities (via an in-order
traversal on the city visit count index), and find out who visits those
cities, by search for each city in the `city_idx` index to get the
`profile_idx`. Grab only unique items, and you have your answer.

**Oh, and something seems wrong here: This seems like an awful lot of code for your instructor to want written in several hours!**

Comment: I had 2 weeks for this but I though had more, the fault is mine... :/